# Web Part Tool Part Customization issue

Tags: web-part, web-part-property

To customize the Web Part Tool Part, im following this tutorial :

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/dudin/archive/2011/04/17/sharepoint-2010-how-to-customize-the-web-part-tool-part.aspx

when i use **On** WebPart "with custom Tool Part" its work fine but when i add a **Second** web part "with custom Tool Part" in the same page and try to edit th custom property i got :

*"The operation could not be completed because the Web Part was deleted by another user or is invalid."*

**Update :**

```
public int _PaginationSize = 5;

[WebBrowsable(false)]
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]

public int PaginationSize
{
     get
     {
       return _PaginationSize;
     }
     set
     {
       _PaginationSize = value;
     }
}
```

```
class Editor : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPart
    {
        private DropDownList list;
        private Label Name;

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            ListeGroupes webPart = (ListeGroupes)this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;
            if (WebPartToEdit == null)
                return;

            Name = new Label();
            Name.Text = "Nbr elements : ";
            Controls.Add(Name);

            list = new DropDownList();
            list.DataSource = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            list.DataBind();
            this.Controls.Add(list);

            base.CreateChildControls();
        }

        public override void ApplyChanges()
        {
            ListeGroupes webPart = (ListeGroupes)this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;
            if (webPart != null)
                webPart.PaginationSize = int.Parse(list.SelectedItem.Value);
        }

        public override void SyncChanges()
        {
            ListeGroupes webPart = this.WebPartToEdit as ListeGroupes;

            if (webPart != null)
            {
                list.SelectedValue = webPart.PaginationSize.ToString();
            }
        }

        public Editor(string webPartID)
        {
            this.ID = "Editor" + webPartID;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, no idea ?!!

Answer (score 4):

You will need to add a ID to your ToolPart (EditorPart).  For example:

```
public MyEditorPart(string webPartID)    
{
  this.ID = "MyEditorPart" + webPartID;  
}
```

http://www.tonstegeman.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=70640fe5-28d9-464f-b1c9-91e07c8f7e47&ID=36

Comment: Thx i will try this ASAP.

Comment: See update still got error

Answer (score 0):

I can't check whole article you followed but I reviewed code samples. At first, you need to use SyncChanges to get initial state for your Tool Part. Also I would mark your custom property as Personalisable, but not WebBrowsable (using Attributes). 
Update: can we see full ToolPart code? that "list" variable looks suspicious.
Update2: at first, if you just want user to pick from a enum with drop down list, you can skip tool part at all: http://www.aidangarnish.net/blog/post/Web-part-custom-property-dropdown-list.aspx; at second, you are using inconsistent way to get a webpart: sometimes this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart, sometimes this.WebPartToEdit. I would use 2nd one everywhere.

Comment: @ivan-padabed i will add SyncChanges and mark my custom property as Personalisable, there is nothing special in my custom code its a gridview that show data from a sharepoint list and i use the custom property to define number elements to show in my gridview **(NB : i got the error when i add 2 webparts in the same page but if use just 1 webpart its work fine)**

Comment: @ivan-padabed : ToolPart code add

Comment: @ivan-padabed : this.WebPartToEdit implemented (still got error), create custom properties work fin but i need to know what is the problem with the custom ToolPart.

Comment: @markov00 : unfortunately I can't test your code because I'm out of my dev env, but it looks good. It could be Content DB issue - could you please try adding your WPs on a brand new page?

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the WebPart's CreateEditorParts method correctly, that's where you're supposed to set the ID

```
public override EditorPartCollection CreateEditorParts()
{
  var editorArray = new ArrayList();
  // set the editor part's id to the webpart's id + identifier (can be anything)
  var editorPart = new MyCoolEditorPart { ID = ID + "_editorPart1" }; 
  editorArray.Add(editorPart);
  var editorParts = new EditorPartCollection(editorArray);
  return editorParts;
```

}

Comment: Yes my editorPart look like your exemple with ID and + identifier